# W key presses tab key, and whole row

Tags: keyboard

It used to be after an hour or two of usage, but now its random. I tried cleaning it, and removing the keycap, cleaning the switch, still doesn't work. Sometimes it only happens when i hold down shift and w. My keyboard is a Logitech G815. Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: On one mechanical keyboard, I've had 2 tiny surface-mount diodes break off the board (likely due to my heavy-handedness). By luck, the pads were clearly visible, shiny, and one of the diodes was still rattling around inside. In that particular case, I was able to check polarity against adjacent diodes, to resolder the found SM diode, and to replace the other with a IN914 component. Hopefully, may your keyboard be as easy to fix -- worth a try, if you'd discard it anyway.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Hopefully. This is a gaming keyboard, one can only imagine what it suffered already, precisely at and around WASD ;)

Comment: what use is a `yes` or a `no` answer? ... please ask about the problem, not about people's experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two key press do this then someone may have spilt a liquid on it. And it may have created a short on the PCB (printed circuit board itself).  Having supplied hardware to pets in the past, a spilt cup of coffee, coke or cat pee can make the keyboard misbehave.

- Take the whole assembly apart (not the keycaps)
- Examine the underside of the board and clean it with IPA
- Similarly the top of the board, where you can be more generous with IPA.

If this doe not work, then it is very likely that the keyboard needs to be replaced.